# how to split one column into two columns base on conditions in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am very new to Excel. Please help

```
Column1
A,1
B,2
C,1
D,2
E,1
```

output:

```
Column2  Column3
A,1       B,2
C,1       D,2
E,1
```

what is the formula to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data ("`A,1`, etc.") spans cells A1:A50, then:

Cell B1: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$50,ROW()*2-1,1)`

Cell C1: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$50,ROW()*2,1)`

Then you can copy the formulas to cells below, as far as needed.
These formulas "redistribute" your cells contents between the two columns, regardless of the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IF condition like this as well

```
    =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="1",A2,"") in column 2
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="2",A2,"") in column 3
```

However cells cannot be deleted just with formula