# Sorting three columns into six, sorted horizontally by surname using excel

Tags: excel, list, vba, sorting

I work at an event centre with a portrait screen either side of the entrance doors that we like to list peoples names and table numbers. We often get the list in the format;

```
Surname  | First Name | Table Number
======================================
Aadomson |    Adam    |      5
Bobson   |    Bob     |      10
```

etc

What we'd love to do is take those three columns and get a script or something (we're a little over our heads) or be pointed in the right direction for something that could sort it to two or three sets of columns (2 lots of surname, first name and table)

To something that goes like

```
Surname  | First Name | Table |  Surname  | First Name | Table
===============================================================
Aadamson |    Adam    |   5   |  Bobson   |     Bob    |  30
Christon |    Chris   |   8   | Donaldson |    Donald  |  40
```

etc

If anyone could shed any help that would be incredible!

Comment: Sort the table and cut and paste the second half next to the first?  I always find that lists sorted across then down are more difficult to scan than when sorted into columns.

Comment: Unfortunately clients can get quite particular, that's what we're doing for now, my bosses are just asking for a solution, just thought i'd see if there is one first! :)

I do agree, but unfortunately not everyone does.

Comment: @EventCentre - Do you have any feedback on posted answers? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356764/2707864) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666516/move-content-from-1-column-to-3-columns/20674518#20674518) for a hint on how to use `INDEX`.

I will use the more general answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800915/2707864) with `OFFSET` (item 8).

Assuming:

- Your source data lays in A2:C3 (you can extend this range as needed),
- Cell D2 contains 3 (your source width)
- Cell D3 contains 2 (the number of repeats)
- Your target range starts at F2

then cell F2: `=OFFSET($A$2,(ROW()-ROW($F$2))*$D$3+INT((COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$2))/$D$2),MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$2)),$D$2))`

Copy this to the right (6 columns) and down as far as needed.